# Dragging map changes search results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3

How would you implement draggable search results with Google maps API v3 akin to the way Yelp does.

My guess is that you would bind to a map move event and link to an anchor like `#l=g:-122.47764587402344,37.75225820732335,-122.37464904785155,37.83419172060041` and pass those bounds through to the search.

Btw, this is for a Rails project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the Map reference: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map

The event "bounds_changed" seems to be what you want.
When it fires you should get the map boundaries using `map.getBounds()` and pass that along to your search.